# Comparing viewshed surface using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, viewshed

I have a couple of viewshed layers produced from specific points on the digital elevation model. Once I got the results, I was thinking about how should I compare them to see which point has bigger viewshed.

How do I measure the visible surface from the viewshed?

I am using ArcGIS for Desktop.

Comment: what do you mean by visible surface from viewshed ?

Comment: My question is, how to see which viewshed is bigger without only observing the different viewsheds? Is it possible?

Comment: The output of the viewshed is a raster surface where each cell is the number of times that cell can be seen from the observation points.  Open the table associated with the viewshed and look at the 'value' attribute.  A summation of all counts with a value greater than 0 times the cell height times width is the area of that viewshed.